# HttpURLConnection in android doesn't send correct User-Agent header

Tags: java, android, http-headers, user-agent

I have found an issue. I have a server that uses User Agent header to identify the device that is connecting to it. But when i connect to the server using HttpURLConnection i get no User Agent header, but when i connect with the browser it sends the correct User Agent.

For testing i am using an echo server that replies with the headers it found on the request.

When i connect with browser i get:
eg: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 1.5; en-fr; HTC Hero Build/CUPCAKE) AppleWebKit/528.5+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.1.2 Mobile Safari/525.20.1 Up.Link/6.3.1.20.06.3.1.20.0.

But when i connect by code with UrlConnection i get:

User-Agent: UNAVAILABLE.

Does anyone know we i get different behaviors? How i can i connect in the same way the browser does?

**EDIT:**

What i really need is not only the User-Agent header, i also need some special headers (x-up-subno actually). This header is added by the APN of the operator, but for some reason when i connect by code that headers are not added to the request.

From browser:
[image: browser]

From code:
[image: code]

Thanks,

Comment: I think you'll find most HTTP connection libraries don't send a User-Agent themselves, but do provide ways of adding headers to the request so that you can add your own meaningful one.

Comment: It's really not a good idea to sniff User-Agent, there are a variety of problems you will face with unknown and lying agents, blocking software, proxies and caches. If you can find any other way at all to signal that you want a special Android-oriented page, do that.

Answer (score 10):

The [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) states that all clients are supposed to sent User-Agent headers. It however, does not state that they should identify the client in the manner a server wishes to. Android therefore complies with the specification, and there is not a lot you can do about it.

The best you could do is to use the [setRequestProperty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to attempt to get a preferable user-agent value in the request. There are no guarantees that it would work, but it is likely. The method needs to be called in the following manner:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","MyAppName/1.0");
```

The stock Android browser uses WebKit. If you want to set WebKit's user-agent string, you'll either have to use a static value, or read the user-agent string from WebKit. I haven't attempted this, but the WebKit user-agent string is available in Android via the [getUserAgentString() method of the WebSettings class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getUserAgentString%28%29).

Comment: I know about this, but how i can use the same type of connection string that the browser is using? I don't want to hardoced a user-agent myself, i want to use the device user-agent.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a possible solution.

Comment: @answer: The HTTP spec uses the word "should" not "must". This indicates that it would be nice, but you aren't "supposed" to.

@Lucas S: Why would you want to identify yourself as the browser when you AREN'T the browser?

Comment: Nice to know that. Didnt know a separate RFC existed for that purpose.

Comment: I need to do this so my server can identify which device is sending the request. I attached some pics with the output i get when connecting with the browser and by code.

Answer (score -1):

it's be wrong if HttpURLConnection faked the user agent of the browser. it's not the browser after all. it would be nice if it sent a little more information, like maybe "Java/1.6 (MacOS 10.5 ..." etc.

Comment: What is the reason behind of answering after 3 years.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman This is a question-and-answer site, not a forum. Please only post an answer if you have helpful information to add.

Comment: The site is effectively a forum when you are directed to run a search on the question database before submitting a question to determine if your question has been asked before.